# Django waitress- How to run it in Daemon Mode

Tags: python, django, windows, daemon, waitress

I've a django application with waitress (gunicorn doesn't work on windows) to serve it. Because its production code and its based on windows 2012 server. But I want the django application to run in daemon mode is it possible?

Daemon mode - app running without command prompt opening/visible also it'll be helpful to open the shell without closing the server. AutoStart if for some reason system has to restart.

Note:

Limitations: The project cannot be moved to UNIX based system.
Third-Party applications like any .exe file cannot be used.
You cannot use Docker as it consumes a lot of space.

Comment: Have a look at: https://www.devdungeon.com/content/run-python-wsgi-web-app-waitress it goes into depth on how to run python applications as a windows service

Comment: @nigel239, The solution you shared can't be used because it involves Third Party app to be downloaded and set the path to the environment. Also, I think it's not a feasible solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For production:
create a file server.py at same level as manage.py and add following:

```
from waitress import serve
    
from myapp.wsgi import application
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    serve(application, port='8000')
```

`Start-Process python -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList "server.py"`
You can close the terminal after that and it still runs.
If you later want to stop, you have to do with Get-Process and then
TaskKill
**Running with CMD**:

START "myapp" /B python server.py
[Running in cmd](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

Comment: will it work on system restart? I don't think it'll work. Also is there a way to programmatically stop it?

Comment: @jeevu94 you can set a job in the windows task scheduler perhaps?  Windows also has dedicated startup folders, the folder for all users can be found like so: `WIN + R` -> `shell:startup`.  You can create a batch file to run the nescessary commands on startup, and there is a way to hide the terminal in Windows. All of this can be automated through powershell or python. Maybe create a second python socket server, listening for commands to close a process perhaps (Maybe Windows has some native features). More info on hiding Windows terminal: https://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_hideconsole.php

Comment: Kill a process remotely through windows, on another windows instance: https://www.windows-commandline.com/kill-remote-process/

Comment: @Shen is there an alternative command for the command prompt? coz the command you mentioned will work only on Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `&` at the end of command

Comment: can you give me exact command?

Comment: if you said to put & in this command ```python manage.py runserver &``` no this is not working on windows. That will still work in the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution - to use Docker, and in your docker you can use gunicorn or any other linux  feature

Comment: Updated description. I cannot use docker coz of space issues.